# GIT smudge filter on branch switch: How to get log from "new" branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-filter

I am using a smudge filter to expand keywords (e.g. Commit Hash, Author, Date). The script is written in python and triggers "git log" in a subprocess to retrieve the information. Everything works fine if I delete a file and check it out again.

But when I am switching branches, the information expanded into the files is wrong. I figured out that the smudge script runs before the HEAD switches to the branch I want to check out, which makes sense to me. So in that case "git log" will give me the information of the branch I am coming from and not the branch I am switching to.

How can I know which branch is to be checked out in a smudge script? Or how do I retrieve information from the branch I am switching to?

Comment: The last time I checked, that information was not available. This is a bit unfortunate: it probably should be passed as, e.g., an environment variable.

Comment: Please upvote, if you think this question is a good one. I would like to contribute to another question with a comment and due to the reputation system, I am not allowed to write comments.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the commit hash nor the ref being checked out are available to smudge and clean filters. It could possibly be passed in the new `filter.<driver>.process` form as an attribute, but nobody has implemented that in Git yet.

If you want to implement just the commit hash, you can specify the `ident` attribute in the `.gitattributes` file in your repository, like so:

```
*.c ident
```

and then you can write `$Id$` in your code and it will be expanded automatically. That's the only thing that's possible in this case.

Comment: As far as I know, "ident" will expand the blob hash and not the commit hash.

Answer (score 0):

The information you're after is available in the post-checkout hook, but the expansions you're doing are typical of deployment work, for which `git archive | tar Cx` is more appropriate and allows selective keyword expansion and more via the `export-subst` and `export-ignore` attributes.  The problem with making Git ~just a little more friendly~ for deployment tasks is, it never ends.  For development work, Git simply doesn't have the limitations that prompted the facility; as you've noticed everything you need is available from `git log`, since you've got the actual history right there anyway, and you're making a stale duplicate for which the best you can hope is it's not out of date.

Comment: I know about git archive, but it does not match my use case. Every local file shall be marked, so if a developer copies a file to somewhere else, you still have a trace to GIT. There is no way around.
If the developer uses "git archive" everything is fine anyway.